# Multiple object events for one function?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make an html page with 3 sliders for the background (R,G,B)

I want each slider to call a function that changes the background on input, but I can't get it to work unless I rewrite the function for each event. Please bear with me, I'm a new coder and most of this is spaghetti

```js
var red = document.getElementById("red"); //slider values
var routput = document.getElementById("reddemo"); //display values
routput.innerHTML = red.value; //for function

var green = document.getElementById("green");
var goutput = document.getElementById("greendemo");
goutput.innerHTML = green.value;

var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
var boutput = document.getElementById("bluedemo");
boutput.innerHTML = blue.value;

red.oninput && blue.oninput && green.oninput = function() {
  //this is what I want to do; string all of these oninputs together... obviously this way doesn't work
  var x = Math.round([Number(red.value) + Number(blue.value) + Number(green.value)] / 3);
  //this is for later, the text color in body changes to white when color values get too low 

  routput.innerHTML = Math.round(this.value);
  boutput.innerHTML = Math.round(this.value);
  goutput.innerHTML = Math.round(this.value);

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + routput.innerHTML + "," + routput.innerHTML + "," + routput.innerHTML + ")";

  if (x < 127.5) {
    document.body.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  } else {
    document.body.style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Red</p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="red">
  <p>Value: <span id="reddemo"></span></p>
</div>
<p>Green</p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="green">
  <p>Value: <span id="greendemo"></span></p>
</div>
<p>Blue</p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="blue">
  <p>Value: <span id="bluedemo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript are first-class citizens, meaning you can treat a function as a variable:

```
var changeBackground = function () {…};

red.oninput = changeBackground;
blue.oninput = changeBackground;
…
```

Comment: Or even `red.oninput = blue.oninput = green.oninput = function() {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution - Makhiel's is also correct is:

```
red.oninput = blue.oninput = green.oninput = function() {
```

`&&` is 'logical and' in JavaScript: it always turns into true or false. Though "Set red.oninput and blue.oninput to the same function" works in english, the *and* in English doesn't translate to the and in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward using the [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection).
Changed the elements into more semantic as well as functional form control elements: [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output), [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset),[`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend), and [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Used [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get all 3 values to mix in one value.

The key to reducing the number of functions and events is to use [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) by having an element that is a common ancestor to the ranges, listen for the input event. Then by referencing the [**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) we can determine exactly which range is interacting with the user.

BTW in this case, there's no need to convert any values to a number because the value the CSS takes as a RGB color is actually a string that has chars that represent numbers.

### Update

Added a second Demo that does the same thing as Demo 1, but with very minimal code by using **[On Event Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)**. Although the use of them is strongly discouraged I've seen a growing trend of it's use in current but minor code such as this.

### Demo 1

**Details commented in Demo**

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 40%;
  height: 15vh
}

output {
  transform: translate(5px, -7px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='rgb'>

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Red</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="red0">
      <output id="redO"></output>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Green</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="grn0">
      <output id="grnO"></output>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Blue</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="blu0">
      <output id="bluO"></output>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
  <script>
    //Reference the form
    var form = document.forms.rgb;
    //Reference all of form's form controls
    var rgb = form.elements;
    //Register input event on form
    form.addEventListener('input', composeColor);

    // Callback function pass Event Object
    function composeColor(e) {
      //if the node interacting with user is type=range...
      if (e.target.type === "range") {
        // Reference active range
        var rng = e.target;
        // Get range's "little brother" output 
        var viewVal = rng.nextElementSibling;
        // Sync their values
        viewVal.value = rng.value;
        // Collect the values of all ranges then interpolate them
        // into a template literal.
        // The TL is the color of body
        document.body.style.background = `rgb(${red0.value}, ${grn0.value}, ${blu0.value})`;
      } else return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2

[**On Event Attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 40%;
  height: 15vh
}

output {
  transform: translate(5px, -7px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='rgb' oninput="document.body.style.background = `rgb(${red0.value},${grn0.value}, ${blu0.value})`">

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Red</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="red0" oninput='redO.value = this.value'>
      <output id="redO" for='red0'></output>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Green</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="grn0" oninput='grnO.value = this.value'>
      <output id="grnO" for='grn0'></output>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="slidecontainer">
      <legend>Blue</legend>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" class="slider" id="blu0" oninput='bluO.value = this.value'>
      <output id="bluO" for='blu0'></output>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
  <script>
  
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```